# How do I make the if/else statement get checked every time my function is called (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, behavior

so what I am trying to do is make the if/else statement in the function below get checked every time the function is called. I call it using

onclick="openNav()"

in my HTML. Thank you so much for your help, sorry if this is a lame question as I am new to JavaScript.

Code below:

```js
var intViewportWidth = window.innerWidth;

function openNav() {

 $("body").css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,.4)");

 if (intViewportWidth < 1200) {

  $("header nav").css("width", "100%");
  $("body").css("margin-right", "100%"); 

 }
 else {

  $("header nav").css("width", "30%");
  elBody.css("margin-right", "30%");

 }

 $("#hamburger").hide();

}
```

Comment: Try moving `var intViewportWidth = window.innerWidth;` inside your function.

Comment: It works, thank you. :)

Comment: Sure thing!  When you call `openNav()` using `onclick`, your function has no idea what `intViewportWidth` represents.  Your browser probably throws a reference error because the variable isn't defined, and your conditional logic is never reached.  You probably want to evaluate the window width whenever you call this function anyway, so that your nav can respond with the proper styles applied.

Comment: ohhh okay that makes sense

Comment: Incidentally unless you define `elBody` somewhere else in your code you'll probably not get that `margin-right` property set when your window size is over 1200px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below snippet. Unless getting width is inside function, intViewportWidth will not change.

```js
function openNav() {
    
 $("body").css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,.4)");
    
    var intViewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
 if (intViewportWidth < 1200) {

  $("header nav").css("width", "100%");
  $("body").css("margin-right", "100%"); 

 }
 else {

  $("header nav").css("width", "30%");
  elBody.css("margin-right", "30%");

 }

 $("#hamburger").hide();

}
```